# iOS: how to invoke the system image viewer with a network image?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app that will show some images using UIImageView, now I want to add a functionality that when user clicks the UIImageView it opens the image in the iOS image application(can zoom in/out, save the image,etc).

Comment: When you say system image viewer, we have no idea what the hell is that...please rephrase your question. Tell us where the image is? on network? where? on another device? you want to do a zooming gesture on phone but the image zooming must be done on other device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not have a default image viewer. You'll need to implement a view controller in your application that can view/zoom/pan and save the image you've downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is no Controller For Images such as the one for Video/Audio ,mail .etc...

if you want just to zoom in/out ,save !! you may simply use `UIScrollView` as superView For your `UIImageView`For Zooming 
 and for saving use this Code

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(scratchImage.image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

I hope that helps!!